# Factor analysis in preparation for Rasch

Tags: factor-analysis, rasch

I'm breaking into Rasch modelling and finding it very useful. However I'm just trying to find a way to begin making use of techniques I was familiar with when using classical test methods, such as factor analysis.

I have a large set of items (k = 59), and I wish to uncover which items correspond to which sub-scales/constructs. I have done so, and have the items each keyed to one of three underlying factors.

I now wish to take each subscale and use Rasch modelling to uncover item parameters, etc.

My question is this - is this a reasonable method to be using? FA and Rasch come from rather different families of models so using both feels rather obtuse to me. Is a method recommended for Rasch modelling that specifically searches out for multidimensionality in the dataset while uncovering parameters?

Cheers in advance!

Comment: The two models are actually very closely related.

Comment: ah! in that case:

A) would you say I am on the right track?
B) interesting that you say so - FA is a correlational model whereas Rasch seems to use a completely different methodology;  perhaps I don't see the link? Out of interest could you elaborate?
C) I love your books. I literally have one on my bedside table. *swoon*

Comment: I mean, if I was doing factor analysis using polychoric correlations (I'm not) I can certainly see the link but not otherwise

Comment: Thanks. :) If you use the ML estimator in Mplus, you have an IRT model. Here's a paper: http://www.unc.edu/~dbauer/manuscripts/kamata-bauer-2008.pdf

Comment: Your items are dichotomous - so you shouldn't be doing regular correlations - polychoric correlations estimate the true correlation of the items.  Also, you can do exploratory IRT, which is very closely related to factor analysis: Here's a page from the nice people at SAS: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/66859/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_irt_examples02.htm

Comment: The items weren't dichotomous, they were polytomous, hence I overlooked using polychoric correlations, though of course it certainly would be better to! Either way, that is exactly what I needed, many thanks! You are the hero this website needs :)

Comment: Rasch models are dichotomous, that's why I assumed they were. Other IRT models aren't necessarily dichotomous though.

Comment: You can run the unidimensional Rasch model on each subscale if you have a theoretical idea of what those scales are a priori. You can also start with all items in one rasch model and run a PCA of the standardized residuals for the fitted model. This will reveal any sub dimensions, and you can break your scale up accordingly. Also, there are variants of Rasch for polytomous data. See Lincare's work.